# How to add new languages to Pidgin spellchecker in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, pidgin, input-languages

When you write a message in Pidgin, you rightclick on the input and you can choose from Languages menu in which language you write. What to do when there is no language you want in the menu (in Debian)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the Pidgin site you can read that Pidgin will use any of the GtkSpell dictionaries you have installed:

https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#SpellChecking

But I was confused when I searched the packages list with aptitude for `gtkspell`, because I only found `libgtkspell`, no packages with particular languages. The secret is these packages names begin with `myspell-`, for example to install Polish language do:

```
sudo aptitude install myspell-pl
```

I restarted Pidgin and new language was available on the list.

Comment: Seems that myspell was replaced by hunspell, so cipricus’ answer seems to be the correct one now.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated [here](http://linuxblog.darkduck.com/2014/06/how-to-enable-spell-check-in-pidgin-linux.html):

> You need to install additional spellcheckers. Navigate to your
>   system's package management tool and search for the package
>   hunspell-, for example hunspell-ru for Russian. If it
>   does not exist, search for myspell-. Both hunspell- and
>   myspell- dictionaries are supported by Mozilla and OpenOffice, so you
>   have a good chance of finding these dictionaries for your
>   distribution. The difference between hunspell and myspell is that the
>   latter one is deprecated for many languages, and the former one
>   replaces the outdated version

For many languages the way to go is:

```
sudo apt-get install hunspell-<your_lang>
```

replacing `your_lang` as needed.